# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity & Securing Folders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Well, I'm at a loss.  I've looked everywhere and I'm still getting errors.  I have a folder with a couple of pdf files stored in it.  The folder is called "docs" and it's in the root directory of my project.  I placed a web.config file in the folder with the following code...

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I also tried placing the code in my root web.config file using the following code...

```
<location path="/docs">    
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Both of these code blocks produce a 500 server error.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to the detailed server error since I'm on shared hosting.  Any ideas?

**Edit**: Sorry... That's what I get for posting a question a 1am.  I want to secure the folder so that only those users who are logged in and authorized can access it and download files.

Comment: Have you tried this locally? Although, if your code is trying to read files from a folder that's denied, an exception (and a resulting 500 error) is expected. You'll get a 403 only if the browser tries to access the pdf's url directly, or if you explicitly return it in code if an access denied exception occurs

Comment: To OP, what were you expecting anyway?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly allow some users?

Comment: Sorry, guys.  See my edit above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943050/asp-net-identity-protecting-a-directory-from-unauthenticated-users)). The solution was to add the web.config to the directory but also to add a handler directive to it. This worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PDFHandler" verb="*"
        path="*.pdf"
        type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"
        resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  This solution worked for me!  Adding the handler was a great idea.

Comment: Of course, this works for *all* authorized users, regardless of roles. If you want to restrict on a per-role (or even per-claim) basis, you have to actually work *through* MVC, which means using a script to handle (pass off) the file to be downloaded, and in the process, check the role or claim of the user to see if they have the correct role or claim. Of course, if you are comfortable with security by obscurity this could be as simple as listing the links on a controller/action that has the appropriate restrictions flagged. More secure methods will actually require a hand-off script.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to secure the folder so that only those users who are logged
>   in and authorized can access it and download files.

If you just want to restrict downloads to logged-in and authenticated users, then [GlenBee’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27984709/932002) is by far the simplest and most effective one.

If you need to restrict access by role and/or claim, you have two choices:

1. If you are comfortable with security by obscurity, you can control access to the page that has the links to the files. The files are stored within the wwwroot, so that all you need to do is link to them on a page that does the role/claim filtering. The downside is that anyone can guess the file paths and names, and gain access to them without having the correct role/claim (although you should still secure the file directory for only authenticated users as per GlenBee’s solution).
2. If you need to ensure that, *without exception*, no-one can access the files except those people authorized to do so by virtue of their role/claim (or some other requirement, such as direct ownership), you will have to protect not just the page with the links (filtering for role/claim/ownership), but also create a file handler that passes the files off to the user to be downloaded (filestream, etc.), and to have the files themselves stored outside of wwwroot so they cannot be accessible via plain HTTP. This ‘file hand-off script’ ensures that the user being handed the file actually has the role/claim/ownership required, instead of just being able to blindly guess the path to the file; and storing the file outside of wwwroot ensures that only the script can grab the file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing, here is the contents of the web.config that I placed in the folder:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

And with the errors:

A simple solution I do is turn on health monitoring and have it email me errors, this is in my root web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <healthMonitoring enabled="true">
      <eventMappings>
        <clear/>
        <!-- Log ALL error events -->
        <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
        <!-- Log application startup/shutdown events -->
        <!--<add name="Application Events" type="System.Web.Management.WebApplicationLifetimeEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>-->
      </eventMappings>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <!-- Provide any customized SqlWebEventProvider information here (such as a different connection string name value -->
        <add name="SqlWebEventProvider" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823" buffer="false" type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider"/>
        <add name="EmailWebEventProvider" buffer="false" type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider" from="website@example.com" to="webmaster@example.com" subjectPrefix="Website Error: "/>
      </providers>
      <rules>
        <clear/>
        <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="SqlWebEventProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00"/>
        <!--<add name="Application Events Default" eventName="Application Events" provider="SqlWebEventProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00"/>-->
        <add name="All Errors To E-Mail" eventName="All Errors" provider="EmailWebEventProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00"/>
      </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
</system.web>

<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="no_reply@example.com">
        <network host="mail.example.com" userName="website@example.com" password="P@$$w0rd"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```